# Alphabetize the list of Network Sites

Tags: feature-request, footer, network-sites

Currently, the list of network sites in the footer is organized by graduation date:

[image: network list]

While this can be okay for a short list of sites, since the ones most likely to be clicked will be listed first, when there are 34 sites listed, it gets a bit confusing. If I'm looking for a specific site, I don't know where in the list to begin looking.

Can this list be alphabetized to make it easier to find a specific site?

Comment: @Oded Wouldn't alpha order make it easier to navigate to a specific site? And graduation date is not even the order of the sites most likely to be clicked, since a new site can end up more popular then an older site, so ordering by graduation date does not seem to be the most logical choice.

Comment: What you're saying makes good sense, but no one looks in the footer for sites anyway. They go [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites#newest), where you can sort however you want.

Comment: @CodyGray It may be true that not too many people navigate to the network sites through the footer, but for the times that people do use it, I still think it should be ordered in the most logical and usable manner.

Comment: @TotZam Usability isn't absolute.  You might find it more usable to have them sorted alphabetically, others might not.  I know I don't find that sorting particularly useful as the top results in an alphabetical sort are almost never the site's that I'm looking for, and if you *are* looking to search for a specific site, there are lots of places much better suited to doing so than the footer (say, the header where you can do an actual proper *search* for a site).  Saying that alphabetical order would be more usable to *you* is fine, but asserting that it's more usable for *everyone* is false.

Comment: @Servy I hear that point. Graduation date does not seem to be the best choices at all though. I can hear the argument to order the sites by most popular, but I don't see how having them in graduation date order can ever make it more usable.

Comment: @TotZam calculating the popularity of a given site is going to have a lot of overhead. Generally sites made earlier on are going to be the most popular (with some exceptions) and sites made later on are still going to be less popular (with some exceptions). So in effect, sorting by graduation date _is_ sorting by popularity (with some exceptions).

Comment: @TinyGiant Good point. I still personally think alpha order is easier to navigate, but I guess the best sort order really depends on SO's main purpose of the site list and can really only be determined through user testing.

Comment: Let's imagine, just for a moment, that we have an option that lets us get this list in alphabetical order...

Comment: This question really belongs on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions) as it's not specific to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ChristianDean I thought that too until I realized that this new footer was only introduced to the Stack Overflow site, and is not yet on the rest of the network sites.